# Get all gallery images

Tags: magento2, object, gallery-image

I'm trying to pull through the gallery images on the product page because customizing the gallery with code:

```
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $gallery = $_product->getMediaGalleryImages(); ?>

<?php foreach ($gallery as $galleries): ?>
  <figure><?php echo $galleries ?></figure>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

But first image is not loading. How fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to get Array of gallery images in **gallery.phtml** file

```
$loop=json_decode($block->getGalleryImagesJson());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try in this way (with objectmanager)

```
<?php
    $_product = $block->getProduct();
    $objectmanager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $product_id = $_product->getId();
    $productimages = array();
    $product = $objectmanager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);
    $productimages = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
    foreach ($productimages as $productimage) {

        echo "<img src=" . $productimage['url'] . " alt=" . $_product->getName() . ">";

    }
    ?>
```